# Why does my jQuery post request not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am new to programming, especially jQuery.

I have a script and was testing it in Google Chrome. But when I tried to use IE or Firefox it would only load the first Post request and not the ones in the `.click` function. Here is a link to the  [page in question](http://studyonthefly.com/Questionnaire/Main.php?Grade=Grade1Math&GameName=SingleDigitAddition&Category=SingleDigitAddition). It suppose to display an `X` img when you click `CheckAnswer` and a new question when you click `NextQuestion` unless you login but Firefox/IE display nothing.

Here is the code:

This Works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    HideImg(); 

    $.post("/Post/Number/NextQuestion.php",
    {
      QuestionPart1Legnth: "9",
      QuestionPart2Legnth: "9",  
      GameName: "Addition"
    },
    function(data, status) {
      //alert("Data: " + data );
      dbreply = (data);

      xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
      $xml = $( xmlDoc );
      $title = $xml.find( "QuestionPart1" );
      $( "#QuestionPart1" ).empty().append( $title.text() );
      $title = $xml.find( "QuestionNum" );
      QuestionNum = ( $title.text() );
      $title = $xml.find( "QuestionPart2" );
      $( "#QuestionPart2" ).empty().append( $title.text() );
    });
});
```

This Does not:

```
$("NextQuestion").click(function() {
    HideImg(); 
    $.post("/Post/Number/NextQuestion.php",
    {
      QuestionPart1Legnth:"9",
      QuestionPart2Legnth:"9",   
      GameName:"Addition"    
    },
    function(data, status) {
      //alert("Data: " + data );
      dbreply = (data);

      xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
      $xml = $( xmlDoc );
      $title = $xml.find( "QuestionPart1" );
      $( "#QuestionPart1" ).empty().append( $title.text() );
      $title = $xml.find( "QuestionPart2" );
      $( "#QuestionPart2" ).empty().append( $title.text() );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the #  `$("NextQuestion")`( I guess your are not using custom html elements. )

Also you might want to declare your variables `var dbReply, xmlDoc...`:

Comment: Thank you the # was the problem and I was declaring my variables but i did not include it in the code snippet.